# Transfer UTM Parameters From One Page To Another with GTM

Tags: javascript, utm

I am having trouble passing my UTM parameters between all of my pages.

Here is my code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function() {
 var utmInheritingDomain = "mysite.com", // REPLACE THIS DOMAIN 
 utmRegExp = /(\&|\?)utm_[A-Za-z]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+/gi,
 links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
 utms = [
 "utm_source={{url - utm_source}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE utm_source
 "utm_medium={{url - utm_medium}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE utm_medium
 "utm_campaign={{url - utm_campaign}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE utm_campaign
 "utm_content={{url - utm_content}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE utm_content
 "fbclid={{url - fbclid}}", // IN GTM, CREATE A URL VARIABLE fbclid
 ];
 
 for (var index = 0; index < links.length; index += 1) {
 var tempLink = links[index].href,
 tempParts;

 if (tempLink.indexOf(utmInheritingDomain) > 0) { // The script is looking for all links with the utmInheritingDomain
 tempLink = tempLink.replace(utmRegExp, "");

 tempParts = tempLink.split("#");

 if (tempParts[0].indexOf("?") < 0 ) {
 tempParts[0] += "?" + utms.join("&"); // The script adds UTM parameters to all links with the domain you've defined
 } else {
 tempParts[0] += "&" + utms.join("&");
 }

 tempLink = tempParts.join("#");
 }

 links[index].href = tempLink;
 }
 }());
</script>
```

This breaks every time I try to click on multiple links within my site (I put in mysite.com for the example code, but it has my usual domain in Google Tag Manager.)

All I want to be able to do is to pass my query string to any page the visitor clicks on within my site.